# SQL Server extract specific value from string which can contain duplicates/nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, string

I am trying to find the best way to extract specific values from a string which can contain nulls/duplicates for the values. The issue is I have to do this in a query and pull those values into a view for use down the line.

Example of the string:

```
ABCD: 123 EFG: 03 HIJ: NGAB XYZ:  XYZ: 133
EFG: 03 HIJ: NGAB XYZ: 133
```

I am trying to extract the values for `ABCD`, `EFG`, `HIJ`, and `XYZ`.

For example, the first string should return:

```
123 (for value of ABCD)
03 (for value of EFG)
NGAB (for value of HIJ)
133 (for value of XYZ)
```

Second string should return:

```
NULL (for value of ABCD)
03 (for value of EFG)
NGAB (for value of HIJ)
133 (for value of XYZ)
```

The length of the values to return are always static (i.e. ABCD will always be ABCD and 123 will always be the length of the value to return - i.e 3 characters. Same applies for EFG and 03 - EFG will always be EFG and 03 will always be 2 characters and so on).

I am trying to use below to try and return my values:

```
SELECT substring(replace(replace(TEMPFIELD,' ',''),':',''), charindex('XYZ',replace(replace(TEMPFIELD,' ',''),':',''))+3,3) AS XYZ FROM MYTABLE
```

I change my query per field and adjust the length on the substring as needed. The issue is that when there are duplicates, I return the wrong values and when there are nulls, I return the wrong value.

For example, my query returns `XYZ` as the value of XYZ in the first string instead of `123`. It also returns `03H` as the value of ABCD in the second string instead of `NULL`. Is there a better function for me to use in this case to handle both scenarios of nulls/duplicates?

Updated query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TEMPFIELD LIKE '%XYZ%XYZ%' 
            THEN     substring(stuff(replace(replace(TEMPFIELD ,' ',''),':',''),charindex('XYZ',replace(replace(TEMPFIELD ,' ',''),':','')),3,''), charindex('XYZ',stuff(replace(replace(TEMPFIELD ,' ',''),':',''),charindex('XYZ',replace(replace(TEMPFIELD ,' ',''),':','')),3,''))+3,3)
       WHEN TEMPFIELD LIKE '%XYZ%' 
            THEN  substring(replace(replace(TEMPFIELD ,' ',''),':',''), charindex('XYZ',replace(replace(TEMPFIELD ,' ',''),':',''))+3,3) 
       ELSE NULL 
  END AS XYZ
```

Comment: Is database normalization an option?  It seems the table design is not conducive to easy querying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally if you can you would want to sort out the string you are trying to pass as this could get very messy, but I can offer you this solution, based on the following assumptions:

- Duplicated keys only occur twice as per your example
- The values cannot contain the key
- That when the keys are duplicated that the last one is the value you want.

```
  CASE WHEN TEMPFIELD LIKE '%XYZ%XYZ%' 
            THEN SUBSTRING(TEMPFIELD, CHARINDEX('XYZ: ', TEMPFIELD, CHARINDEX('XYZ: ', TEMPFIELD) + 1) + 5, 3)
       WHEN TEMPFIELD LIKE '%XYZ%' 
            THEN SUBSTRING(TEMPFIELD, CHARINDEX('XYZ: ', TEMPFIELD) + 5, 3) 
       ELSE NULL 
  END AS XYZ
```

Add in the replacements if you really need to but if you know the format is reliable enough you shouldn't need to do this as it will just add processing time.

To explain what this does a bit: the first case statement will deal with the duplicated values by getting the `CHARINDEX` of the second key, if that case criteria does not match then it will fall to the second case and do something similar to what you were already doing and finally if the string does not match either of those it simply gives you null.

Comment: Thank you. I came up with the following to get duplicates out based on your solution. This solution will only work when data is presented in such a way with no extra duplicates and as you mentioned.    I put my updated query in my post above. I did use replace still because I'm not sure if the data will be reliable enough. I'll remove them out once I run through a couple thousand test cases.